# How to test if string is 0 or positive integer in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to allow 0 or positive integers as input. The best solution I saw was

```
/^[0-9]+$/.test(input)
```

but this expression will allow the user to use `"010"`, so I changed the expression to

```
/^(0|[1-9]+[0-9]*)$/.test(input)
```

Is that correct? Does this expression handle every input?

Comment: There are a lot of regex testers put there, try this one to test it out with some test input: http://regexhero.net/tester/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That expression says

- `0`, or
- `1-9` followed by 0 or more `0-9`

Here's a visualization: [Link](http://regexper.com/#0|[1-9]%2B[0-9]*).

so yes, that should cover all non-negative integers. Whether or not regular expressions is the right tool for the job is debatable.